# Leaflet JS: defining update function within promise; variation on tutorial

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

A variation on this tutorial: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/. I am attempting to add custom info control.

```js
let info = L.control();
function highlightFeature(e) {
    ...
    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    ...
    info.update();
}

function updateFunction(tab, props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Active Covid-19 Cases </h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + getActive(tab, props.name) + ' cases'
        : 'Hover over a state');
}

info.onAdd = function(map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");
    this.update();
    return this._div;
}

let statedata = fetch(url + stateurl).then(data => data.json());
statedata.then((data) => {
    info.update = (props) => updateFunction(data, props);
    let style = (feature) => styleMap(data, feature); 
    info.addTo(mymap);

    geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {style : style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(mymap);    
});
```

Here, my `info.update` is slightly different from the tutorials. `info.update` and `style` depend on the json data that I am only able to access inside the asynchronous section on the bottom. However, this code gives me the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`, referring to the `this._div` line of the updateFunction.

I found that if I do either of the following

1. move `let info = L.control()` and all of my functions that depend on `info` inside the promise or
2. define `info.update` outside of the promise,

then the code will work without error. However, option 1 appears hideous and morally incorrect, and option 2 necessitates that I abandon hope of accessing the statedata json. Also, in option 2, I don't understand what difference it makes declaring `info.update` inside or outside the promise. In particular, why declaring info.update inside the promise leads to undefined behavior with `info._div` and declaring `info.update` outside the promise does not?

Any clues as to what is wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial you're working from, this is what they have for `info.update`:

```
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};
```

In this function, `this` will refer to the `info` object. In your code you refactor to this:

```
function updateFunction(tab, props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Active Covid-19 Cases </h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + getActive(tab, props.name) + ' cases'
        : 'Hover over a state');
}
// ...
info.update = (props) => updateFunction(data, props);
```

By using an arrow function that invokes a regular function, you've effectively cut the ties between `info` and `this`. In your case, `this` is probably defaulting to `window`, which would explain why `_div` is undefined.

To fix this you need to explicitly [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `this` to `info`. You could do this:

```
info.update = (props) => updateFunction.bind(info)(data, props);
```

Or even more concise, you can simply bind `this` and the first argument, and skip the arrow function intermediate altogether:

```
info.update = updateFunction.bind(info, data);
```